# C# Winform Textbox Validation Error

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, textbox

I have 4 `textboxes`:

1. amount to pay
2. money (Verify the money of the customer)
3. change (if money is greater than amount)
4. and balance (if money is less than amount)

The last `textbox` is for the input (gets/inputs the money of the customer).

I have placed my code into the `TextChanged` handler of textBoxInput (I'm thinking that every time the user inputs something on that textbox it will be automatically updated):

```
private void textBoxInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBoxMoney.Text = textBoxInput.Text;

    if (int.Parse(textBoxAmount.Text) > int.Parse(textBoxMoney.Text))
    {
        int balance = int.Parse(textBoxAmount.Text) - int.Parse(textBoxMoney.Text);
        textBoxBalance.Text = balance.ToString();
    }

    if (int.Parse(textBoxMoney.Text) > int.Parse(textBoxAmount.Text))
    {
        int change = int.Parse(textBoxMoney.Text) - int.Parse(textBoxAmount.Text);
        textBoxChange.Text = change.ToString();
    }
}
```

It runs correctly, however whenever I press backspace (or clear the data) in the `textbox`, I get a format error. I also get an error when I put a letter in it. How can I prevent it make a will appear if the user inputs a letter and when the data is cleared? Also, another error appears when I put a bigger value for ex.

The amount to pay = 600, I input = 1000, the balance textbox has = 550, the change textbox has = 330. It doesn't compute correctly. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with money, it's usually better to use the `Decimal` type instead of `Integer`, but for your example, it's probably better to use the `TryParse()` method instead of the `Parse`.  The format error happens because when you backspace, the textbox is empty and the parse fails.

Quick rework:

```
private void textBoxInput_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  textBoxMoney.Text = textBoxInput.Text;

  int amount = 0;
  int money = 0;
  int balance = 0;
  int change = 0;

  int.TryParse(textBoxAmount.Text, out amount);
  int.TryParse(textBoxMoney.Text, out money);

  if (amount > money)
    balance = amount - money;
  if (money > amount)
    change = money - amount;

  textBoxBalance.Text = balance.ToString();
  textBoxChange.Text = change.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much Sir! I'm gonna have to research the difference between parse and tryparse :))

Comment: @rjtubera Here is the link to [MSDN: Int32.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx)

Comment: And i suggest to handle KeyPressEvent by not allowing Letter's on these TextBox-es just accept Decimal Number's.